# Mean center Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a movie dataset. The dataset contains ratings from users. For every user I need the mean of all the ratings form that user. This mean I need to substract from every single rating to get the centered mean.

```
mean_user_rating = df_ratings.groupby(['userId'])['rating'].mean().to_frame()
mean_user_rating.rename(columns={"A": "userId", "B": "rating"})
film_user = pd.DataFrame(df_ratings.sort_values('rating', ascending=False))
```

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dff3v.png)

But now I need to substract the mean ratings from the normal ratings but this need to be done on the userId.

**The question and additional info:**

Users have a bias, they do not review in the same way and therefore an absolute rating is less interesting. To make a better system we can look at the average rating of a user and how the given rating deviates from this average. This way you know whether a user relatively finds a film better or worse. In other words, we mean-center the rating. We take the mean, the mean, as the midpoint and rewrite the rating to the deviation from this midpoint.

Once you know the deviation from the center point, you can use this to compare films. For example, you can take the average of the deviation of each rating of a film and use this as a new rating for a film.

Question 25: A better top 5
It is now up to you to draw up a new top 5. This time not based on the average rating, but based on the average mean-centered rating. Again, use df_ratings_filtered as dataset here. Store the top 5 as Series in a variable called top_5_mean_centered with index movieId.

Note, this command is slightly larger. Think carefully in advance which steps you have to go through.

Comment: I don't get the point here could you please provide an example and what you expect.

Comment: you are probably looking for `groupby('user_id')['rating'].transform('mean')` but without and example of your input data and desired output it's hard to tell

Comment: I added a picture of the data

Comment: I found the solution:

df_test_sub = df_ratings_filtered.groupby('userId')['rating'].transform('mean')
new_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(df_ratings_filtered)
new_data_frame['rating'] = df_ratings_filtered['rating'] - df_test_sub.values


top_5_mean_centered = df_ratings_filtered.groupby("movieId").mean().sort_values('rating', ascending=False).head(5)
top_5_mean_centered = Series(top_5_mean_centered.rating)